# How to calculate $\frac{d}{dα}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-\alpha}}{e^x-1}\,dx$ and its convergence or divergence

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I will exactly show you the output of my calculations and the reason why I am struggling with this improper integral. I expanded a function acc. to a McLaurin serie for values of α<<1. I obtained a term that looks like this

$$ \frac{d}{dα}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-α}}{e^x-1}\;\mathrm{d}x$$

As one can see, it is a derivative (not in the variable x but in α)  of an improper integral. What is the right calculation procedure?

- Should I check the convergence of the integral in order to first apply the derivative of integral argument and then integrate?
  $$ \frac{d}{dα}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-α}}{e^x-1}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dα}\frac{x^{2-α}}{e^x-1}\;\mathrm{d}x$$
  The point is, does the integral converge? I cannot get a reliable result on this.
- Or should I first solve the integral and then derivate?
  $$ \frac{d}{dα}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2-α}}{e^x-1}\;\mathrm{d}x = \frac{d}{dα} F(x,α)$$ where F(x,α) is the solution of the improper integral.
  On this regards, how do I solve this improper integral?

Can you please kindly show me a procedure of calculation in detail ? It would be really appreciated. Resumed, my queries concerns:
convergence of the integral and calculation of the integral.

Have a nice day and thank you so much for your professional support!

Comment: Both way is correct. You just choose the easy one.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to determine the convergence of $$-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{ x^{2-\alpha} \log x}{e^x-1} dx $$

Near $x=0$, $e^x-1 \sim x$ so the integrand is asymptotic to $$x^{1-\alpha} \log x \to 0$$

As $x\to \infty$, it’s asymptotic to$$x^{2-\alpha} \log x \cdot e^{-x} $$ and convergence is guaranteed because of the $e^{-x}$. So, the integral converges.

Comment: @Tevish thank you so much. I like pragramatic answers. Just one doubt, should  not actually the convergence of the original argument of the integral be checked ? So that we can afterwards apply the derivative?  M.

Comment: Ideally yes. The original integral can be seen to converge in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. You can do both.

However this integral is a special one. This integral is related to Riemann Zeta function [$\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#:%7E:text=The%20Riemann%20zeta%20function%20%CE%B6%28s%29%20is%20a%20function,be%20written%20as%20a%20converging%20summation%20or%20integral%3A) by the formula
$$ \zeta(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1}\, dx$$ for $s > 1$ where $\Gamma(s) = \int_0 ^ {\infty} e^{-x} x^{s-1} \, dx$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

**Hint:**
This is just a hint and try to formalize the argument;

Try to show that series $\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1} ^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^s}$ converges when $s > 1$ and write
$$ \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x -1} = \frac{e^{-x} x^{s-1}}{1 -e^{-x}} =  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}e^{-kx} x^{s-1}$$  and try to write the integral in terms of $\zeta(s)$ and $\Gamma(s)$ by making proper substitutions since the convergence of both functions are wellknown.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailled clarification. Nevertheless, I am not able to determine if it converges or not. The converning scenario would lead me to first derive the integral and than solve it, the easiets procedure. Could you please check if it converges? I dont expect to see all steps if you dont have the time. Thank you again